# How to Stop Gutenberg From Adding Classic Block

Tags: block-editor

I am using WPBakery for page layout and adding a Gutenberg Editor Block to type text. On saving the post, the Gutenberg Editor adds a gray classic box giving the post a lot more space between paragraphs. Is there anyway to keep this from happening? I have attached an image of an example of what if happening. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: You'll likely need to contact WPBakery support directly, as it sounds specific to that plugin. The normal Block Editor does not add extra Classic blocks.

Comment: I haven't used it without WPBakery so I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for the suggestion.